# How to make use of c++ xpcom component from javascript xpcom component

Tags: javascript, c++, xpcom

I have developed a xpcom component using c++. I have GetHWND() method in my component. I have also developed another xpcom component using javascript. I want to make use of GetHWND function in javascript xpcom component. I am using following code to do so.

> netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
>
> netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
>
> var myComponent = Components.classes['@dougt/WebLock'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.IWebLock);
>
> myComponent = myComponent.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.IWebLock);
>
> var res = myComponent.GetHWND(mainWindow.content.document);

But it is giving error as "ReferenceError: netscape is not defined". I did google search but did not find the solution to it.

I am using Mozilla Firefox and I want it to get worked for the same.

Please help me to come out of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add c++ and javascripts tags to the question to try to get more people to look for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need these:

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nickolay, when your extension code is executed it has chrome privileges, which allow you to access XPCOM layer and components.

What I would like to see is if it will work with the lines Nikolay mentioned out.
And second item >> how your interface of C++ component is defined.
XPIDL doesn't aware of HWND type, so you have to provide some different type, or you can use native type but it's not supported by [scriptable] interfaces